# Pass angular data to scala route

Tags: angularjs, scala, playframework-2.2

I am developing a web app with play framework and angularJs.
And I have the following route.

```
GET     /user/view/:id      controllers.User.view(id:String)
```

GET     /user/view/:id      controllers.User.view(id:String)

And in my view I have a link.

```
<tr>
    <td>#</td>
    <td>{{user.email}}</td>
    <td>{{user.lastname}}</td>
    <td>{{user.firstname}}</td>
    <td><a href="@routes.User.view("{{user.email}}")">More</a></td>
</tr>
```

I don't know how to pass user.email to route.
Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't using server side generated templates. So you should use a $http get.

```
<td><a href="@routes.User.view("{{user.email}}")">More</a></td>
```

Will be

```
<td><a href="" ng-click="showUser(user)">More</a></td>
```

And then in your controller, you can do something like this

```
$scope.showUser = function(user) {
     $http.get('/user/view/'+user.email).then(function(result) {
          $scope.user = result.data;
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: `ng-click="@routes.User.view(user.email)"`

user.email should be part of the `$scope` hence above code should work

Comment: It is not working. Scala assume that user.email is scala variable. Error: Compilation error - object email is not a member of package views.html.user

Comment: Not sure then, I assumed its an angular issue and it fails to make a right call to the server.